# X11 and XLib - incorrect keyboard Input

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

I started studying xlib and ran into a problem. With the help of the Internet, I implemented such an algorithm for reading keyboard button presses. However, it does not work quite correctly - when the button is pressed, the event of releasing is read first, but only the flow of pressing. So I get the following output when pressing and pressing any button:  `RELEASE PRESS RELEASE`. What could be my mistake?

```
int X11EventFilter()
{
   Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);
   if (d == 0)
   {
       qDebug() << "Cannot open display\n";
       exit(0);
   }
   Window root = DefaultRootWindow(d);


   XSetErrorHandler(ErrorHandler);

   Window current_window;
   int rev;
   XGetInputFocus(d, &current_window, &rev);

   XSelectInput(d, current_window, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | FocusChangeMask);
   char keyStr[20];
   KeySym   keySym;
   while (true)
   {
       XEvent e;
       XNextEvent(d, &e);
       switch (e.type)
       {
       case FocusOut:
           XGetInputFocus(d, &current_window, &rev);
           if (current_window == PointerRoot || current_window == None)
           {
               current_window = root;
           }
           XSelectInput(d, current_window, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | FocusChangeMask);
           break;
       case KeyPress:
       {
           memset (keyStr, 0, sizeof (keyStr));
           XLookupString(&e.xkey, keyStr,sizeof (keyStr), &keySym, 0);
           switch (keySym)
           {
           case XK_Control_L:
               qDebug() <<  "\n L_CLTR PRESS \n";
               break;
           case XK_Control_R:
               qDebug() <<  "\n R_CLTR PRESS \n";
               break;
           case XK_Shift_L:
               qDebug() <<  "\n L_SHIFT PRESS \n";
               break;
           case XK_Shift_R:
               qDebug() <<  "\n R_SHIFT PRESS \n";
               break;
           }
           break;
       }
       case KeyRelease:
           memset (keyStr, 0, sizeof (keyStr));
           XLookupString(&e.xkey, keyStr,sizeof (keyStr), &keySym, 0);
           switch (keySym)
           {
           case XK_Control_L:
               qDebug() <<  "\n L_CLTR RELEASE \n";
               break;
           case XK_Control_R:
               qDebug() <<  "\n R_CLTR RELEASE \n";
               break;
           case XK_Shift_L:
               qDebug() <<  "\n L_SHIFT RELEASE \n";
               break;
           case XK_Shift_R:
               qDebug() <<  "\n R_SHIFT RELEASE \n";
               break;
           }
           break;
       }
   }
   XCloseDisplay(d);//*/
   return 0;
}
```

p.s.Okay, I just missed a specific name. For example, I press and release L_CTRL and the output is: `L_CLTR RELEASE  L_CLTR PRESS  L_CLTR RELEASE`. To be precise, it is worth paying attention to the moment of pressing the button, because pressing is accompanied by the output: `L_CLTR RELEASE  L_CLTR PRESS`.

Comment: This code doesn't output _PRESS *or* _RELEASE so I don't see how you could get that output

Comment: @user253751 Okay, I just missed a specific name. For example, I press and release  L_CTRL and the output is: `L_CLTR RELEASE  L_CLTR PRESS  L_CLTR RELEASE`

Comment: you don't have defaults in your switch statements so there may be other unnoticed events.

Comment: @stark I added, but it didn't solve my problem